# Calling "Payment Method" in Order Details

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, payment-methods

I'm calling:

`$payment_name = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle();`

in an extension for payment fees, so I can get the name of the payment method used for that order and display it. The problem is that the order details page (when a user is logged in) and the order details print (on the success page) both lead to an error:

```
The requested Payment Method is not available.

Trace:
#0 /var/www/kd/dev.aaronia-shop.com/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Info.php(82): Mage::throwException('The requested P...')
#1 /var/www/kd/dev.aaronia-shop.com/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Payment.php(218): Mage_Payment_Model_Info->getMethodInstance()

...
```

But sales e-mails, admin-backend and everything else is working fine, just the order details giving me a headache. Commenting out/removing the `$payment_name = ...` line fixes it.

Is there a different way to call for the order payment method?

**Edit:** When I load the working code and log-in as a user, then go to an order details page, load the problematic code and refresh the page - it works. Then I can go back and check other order detail pages, all until I make a new order, then it breaks again and I get the error again when I try to see them.

Answer (score 2):

Use below code

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
$incrementId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
$order->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);

$payment = $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle();
```

Comment: `Fatal error: Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on boolean in /. . . . . ./Fee.php on line 46`

In the line starting with `$payment ...`

Comment: Debug code do you get order increment id  $incrementId there?

Comment: Magento logs are empty and I unfortunately don't have access to PHP debugging (provider is really restrictive).

Comment: order instance is not created there need to check for it

Comment: Okay, I tested something - when I reset the code to the working one and load one of the "Order Details" pages, then **change** the code to your solution (or my one) and reload it, it works - but only until I make a new order, then it's broken again (and orders don't work either with your code btw.).